# Tried to add scrollable bar in sizedbox listview but it didn't work, in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want  add scrollable bar. I tried so many ways but those didn't work.

code

```
 SizedBox(
                                  width: width * 0.9,
                                  height: height * 0.09,
                                  child: RawScrollbar(
                                    thumbColor: Colors.redAccent,
                                    radius: Radius.circular(20),
                                    thickness: 5,
                                    child: StreamBuilder<List<Vaccination>>(
                                      stream: fetchVaccination(petid: widget.id),
                                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                        if (snapshot.hasError) {
                                          return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                                        } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                          List<Vaccination> data = snapshot.data!;
                                          if (data.isEmpty) {
                                            return GestureDetector(
                                              onTap: () {
                                                Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                                  builder: (context) => AddPetVaccinationScreen(
                                                    petid: widget.id,
                                                    petName: onePet!.petName,
                                                  ),
                                                ));
                                              },
                                              child: Container(
                                                height: height * 0.06,
                                                width: width * 0.5,
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                                                  boxShadow: [
                                                    BoxShadow(
                                                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
                                                      spreadRadius: 2,
                                                      blurRadius: 27,
                                                      offset: const Offset(0, 2),
                                                    ),
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                                child: SizedBox(
                                                  child: Card(
                                                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                                                    ),
                                                    child: const Center(
                                                      child: Text(
                                                        'Add Vaccination',
                                                        textScaleFactor: 1.0,
                                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            );
                                          } else {
                                            data.sort((a, b) => b.vaccineDate.compareTo(a.vaccineDate));
                                            return ListView.builder(
                                              itemCount: data.length,
                                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                                return GestureDetector(
                                                  onTap: () {
                                                    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                                      builder: (context) => ViewAllVaccinationsScreen(
                                                        petName: onePet!.petName,
                                                        petid: widget.id,
                                                      ),
                                                    ));
                                                  },
                                                  child: FractionallySizedBox(
                                                    widthFactor: 0.85, // Adjust the width factor as needed
                                                    child: Card(
                                                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                                                      ),
                                                      child: Row(
                                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                                        children: [
                                                          Expanded(
                                                            child: Container(
                                                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0, bottom: 5, left: 10, right: 0,),
                                                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                                                              child: Text(
                                                                data[index].vaccineTitle,
                                                                textScaleFactor: 1.0,
                                                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                              ),
                                                            ),
                                                          ),
                                                          Padding(
                                                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
                                                            child: SizedBox(
                                                              width: width * 0.05,
                                                              height: height * 0.05,
                                                              child: Image.asset(Config.downArrow),
                                                            ),
                                                          ),
                                                        ],
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                );
                                              },
                                            );
                                          }
                                        } else {
                                          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                                        }
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  ),

                                )
```

I think the reason for that is in my code ,if vaccinations are empty, then show add vaccination card. This scenario is unique from what I have found in terms of adding a scorable bar codes. How solve this and add a scrollable bar?